# PowerShell result to HTML report format

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm stuck in outputing the below PowerShell result into a HTML report. I have the below PowerShell script to query through to get replication result.

```bsh
Get-3parRCopy > showrcopy.txt
$a = (Get-Content showrcopy.txt -Raw) -split "(?sm)^Name\s+Target.*?`r?`n" | 
     Select-Object -Skip 1 |
     ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\s')[0] }

foreach ($b in $a) { Get-3parRCopy -groups $b }
```

The result from the above is as below

```
Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name         Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP001Temp   3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 00:08:09 MYT, Period 3h,over_per_alert
  LocalVV        ID   RemoteVV         ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  LUN001-Temp 13304 LUN001-TempDR 16914 Synced        2018-11-04 00:08:10 MYT

Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name              Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP002-PHY01 3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 01:17:54 MYT, Period 2h,auto_recover,over_per_alert
  LocalVV          ID   RemoteVV         ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  LUN001-VVT2.12  120 LUN001-VVT2.12  210 Syncing (33%) 2018-11-03 23:51:04 MYT

Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name              Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP003-PHY02 3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 01:27:12 MYT, Period 1h45m,auto_recover,over_per_alert
  LocalVV          ID   RemoteVV         ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  LUN002-VVT2.14  130 LUN002-VVT2.14  207 Syncing (49%) 2018-11-03 23:59:27 MYT

Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name              Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP001-PRD-ORA 3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 00:45:09 MYT, Period 2h,auto_recover,over_per_alert
  LocalVV                      ID   RemoteVV                     ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  ORA-PROD-VG01.35   97 ORA-PROD-VG01.35 2451 Synced        2018-11-04 00:45:54 MYT
  ORA-PROD-VG02.36   98 ORA-PROD-VG02.36 2452 Synced        2018-11-04 00:46:10 MYT
  ORA-PROD-VG03.37   99 ORA-PROD-VG03.37 2453 Synced        2018-11-04 00:45:48 MYT
  ORA-PROD-VG04.38  100 ORA-PROD-VG04.38 2454 Synced        2018-11-04 00:45:12 MYT
  ORA-PROD-VG05.39  101 ORA-PROD-VG05.39 2455 Synced        2018-11-04 00:45:12 MYT

Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name              Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP001-PRD-SAP 3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 01:24:25 MYT, Period 23m,auto_recover,over_per_alert
  LocalVV                 ID   RemoteVV                ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  SAP-PROD-APPS.4        80 SAP-PROD-APPS.4      1474 Synced        2018-11-04 01:24:28 MYT
  SAP-PROD-LOCK.19       95 SAP-PROD-LOCK.19     1490 Synced        2018-11-04 01:24:25 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT1.5      81 SAP-PROD-SAPDT1.5    1475 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:16 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT2.6      82 SAP-PROD-SAPDT2.6    1476 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:05 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT3.7      83 SAP-PROD-SAPDT3.7    1477 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:07 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT4.8      84 SAP-PROD-SAPDT4.8    1478 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:41 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT5.9      85 SAP-PROD-SAPDT5.9    1479 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:35 MYT
  SAP-PROD-SAPDT6.10     86 SAP-PROD-SAPDT6.10   1480 Synced        2018-11-04 01:25:56 MYT

Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name              Target      Status   Role       Mode     Options
GRP002-PRD-SAP 3PARSYSTEM1 Started  Primary    Periodic Last-Sync 2018-11-04 01:24:55 MYT, Period 23m,over_per_alert
  LocalVV          ID   RemoteVV          ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  SAP-PROD-VG01.10   15 SAP-PROD-VG01.10 29769 Synced        2018-11-04 01:28:44 MYT
```

How can I output the above result into HTML with the format like below.

[image: desired html output]

Comment: `foreach ($b in $a) { Get-3parRCopy -groups $b } | Convertto-Html` , does this work for you?

Comment: directly convertto-html does not work for me..

Comment: Do you actually have the desired html output in text format? (And not only an image) Or do you want us to write the html code too?

Comment: For one thing: don't write cmdlet output to a file then read the file back into PowerShell. That will turn your data into a flat string even if it was a list of structured objects before. What kind of output does your cmdlet produce (`Get-3parRCopy | Get-Member`)? For using `ConvertTo-Html` you need a list of objects. If your output is flat text anyway you'll have to parse it into objects first.

Comment: Hi marsze, i have the resulted output as per above but not in html format. would appreciate if you can help to get code to just convert the data to html format in the desired output just a plain table format that would be suffice. i can try to figure out to get the color coding later on.

Comment: The problem is that you can't go directly from unstructured text to the convertto-html cmdlet. You need the data to be in a format that the cmdlet understands such as the Rows property of a system.data.datatable object or a psobject with name value pairs. Then as others have said you will need to either pass CSS into the header or provide the cmdlet with a CSS uri to include in the file to get the styling. Convertto-html is taking structured data in powershell and turning it into an html table.

Answer (score 0):

ConvertTo-Html cmdlet has a Head parameter that allows you to specify the HTML code that will go into the HEAD element. So you can create CSS style tags to obtain the desired format.

A good article can be found here: https://4sysops.com/archives/building-html-reports-in-powershell-with-convertto-html/

Comment: sorry i have tried to do exactly what was written in the tutorial before.. but the output is not as expected.. but with get-psdrive it produce the same output as per the tutorial.